# Parsing a JSON response after a file upload with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small script using jquery to upload a file to a server. The file is uploaded successfully and the done: event is called with no problems, but I am having issues to process the answer. This is my script:

```
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="carPicture" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <div id="progress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            'use strict';
            // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
            var url = "uploadCarPicture";
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                    });
                },
                fail: function (e, data) {
                    alert("File exists");
                    },
                progressall: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#progress .bar').css(
                            'width',
                            progress + '%'
                    );
                }
            }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
                    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
        });
    </script>
```

I am having two problems:

1. the variable data seems to be empty since the loop below doesn't run even once.

   ```
           $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
               $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
           });
   ```
2. The answer is a JSON document with the following format: {"e":0} where "e" is an error code. "e" could return many different values and I would like to be able to find out the real response and not always assume 0.

Any idea?

Comment: What does your console show as the actual response? It sounds like the resulting object is not in the format that you are expecting. Also, instead of `$.each`, you should be using `$(data).each`.

Comment: If the response is `{"e":0}`, then the object obviously does not have a `result` property, so you cannot iterate over `data.result.files`.

Comment: Solve the second problem and then the first will solve itself

Comment: What are you doing in your controller function, can we get a look?

Comment: Thanks for you answers. What JSON should the server response? I tried {"result" : 0} with no luck. What structure should it have?

Comment: From your code it appears that `data.result.files` should be an array of objects, each object having a property `name`. You wrote the code, didn't you? So how come you don't know what data you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it. I've made a small change in the java script like this:

```
done: function (e, data) {
      $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
          $('<p/>').text(file.name);
        });
      },
```

And I have changed the json that the server was responding to this format:

{ 
  files:
    [
      {
        error: 0,
        name: "thumb2.jpg",
      }
    ]
}